# Using React Component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, reactjs, angular-library

I have a set of react components and i am trying to use them in an Angular 2 app.

Here is the Main React Component that i am trying to use

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import MyCardContainer from './containers/MyCardContainer';
import './assets/style/main.css';
export default class MyCard extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount(){

    }

    render(){
        if(this.props.param1 && this.props.param2) {
            return (
                <Provider store={configureStore()}>
                    <MyCardContainer param1={this.props.param1} param2={this.props.param2} key='container'/>
                </Provider>
            )
        }
        else{
            return(
                <div>
                    Invalid Params are provided for MyCard Component !!
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Now in my angular project i have the following files.

app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { MyCardHostComponent } from './mycardhost.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyCardHostComponent
  ],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

app.component.html

```js
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to React Components Usage Page
  </h1>
  <div>
    <my-card-host></my-card-host>
  </div>
  <div id="my-card"></div>
</div>
```

And mycardhost.component.ts

I tried both OnInit and AfterContentInit . I only had one active at a given time. Initially in the template i didn't have the div with id "my-card" (which i have in

```js
import {Component, ViewChild,ElementRef,AfterContentInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MyCard} from './MyCard';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-card-host',
  templateUrl:"./mycardhost.component.html"
})

export class MyCardHostComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit{

    @ViewChild('my-card') myCard: ElementRef;

    ngOnInit(){
       // MyCard.initialize("param1val","param2val",document.getElementById("my-card"));
    }

    ngAfterContentInit(){
      MyCard.initialize("param1val","param2val",this.myCard.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

and the template file for the mycardhost.component.html which has the div tag with id "my-card" where the React Component will be loaded.

```html
<div id="my-card"></div>
```

And when i run the app the React Store and Reducers are getting initialized. How ever i am getting the following Error: Which indicated the document.getElementById() that i am passing is not a valid DOM Element.

I tried putting break points in the Angular Components and none of them are getting executed. Not sure what i am doing wrong. Really appreciate any help.

```html
Uncaught ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
    at invariant (eval at <an…, …}

   Target container is not a DOM element. at invariant (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1873:1)), <anonymous>:39:15) [<root>] at Object._registerComponent (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1873:1)), <anonymous>:447:200) [<root>] at Object._renderNewRootComponent (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1873:1)), <anonymous>:470:34) [<root>] at Object.wrapper [as _renderNewRootComponent] (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1873:1)), <anonymous>:66:21) [<root>] at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1873:1)), <anonymous>:550:32) [<root>] at render (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1873:1)), <anonymous>:570:23) [<root>] at wrapper (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1873:1)), <anonymous>:66:21) [<root>] at eval (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1873:1)), <anonymous>:54:22) [<root>] at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1873:1), <anonymous>:607:2) [<root>] at __webpack_require__ (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1873:1), <anonymous>:557:30) [<root>] at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1873:1), <anonymous>:88:20) [<root>] at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1873:1), <anonymous>:588:19) [<root>] at __webpack_require__ (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1873:1), <anonymous>:557:30) [<root>] at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1873:1), <anonymous>:580:37) [<root>] at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1873:1), <anonymous>:583:10) [<root>] at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1873:1) [<root>] at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/js/polyfills.js:53:30) [<root>] at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:732:1), <anonymous>:8:27) [<root>] at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:732:1) [<root>] at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/js/polyfills.js:53:30) [<root>] at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:760:1), <anonymous>:7:17) [<root>] at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:760:1) [<root>] at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/js/polyfills.js:53:30) [<root>] at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:746:1), <anonymous>:13:31) [<root>] at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:746:1) [<root>] at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/js/polyfills.js:53:30) [<root>] at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:712:1), <anonymous>:5:20) [<root>] at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:712:1) [<root>] at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/js/polyfills.js:53:30) [<root>] at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1880:18) [<root>] at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/js/polyfills.js:53:30) [<root>] at webpackJsonpCallback (http://localhost:8080/js/polyfills.js:24:23) [<root>] at http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1:1 [<root>]
__zone_symbol__name
:
"Invariant Violation"
```

Comment: im looking to do the same, what is `RepCard.initialize(` do exactly?

Comment: It should be MyCard.initialize("param1val","param2val",this.myCard.nativeElement . While redacting my actual code i forgot to replace one place.

Comment: But how is `MyCard.initialize` _defined_? I'm trying to understand this example but I don't see the source for it included. Presumably it does something like `ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MyCard, props), this.myCard.nativeElement);` but... We're missing the part that shows how actually 1. interact with ReactDOM, 2. pass the props to and create the MyCard React element.

Answer (score 3):

Finally i am able to resolve the Issue.

All i needed to change was the way i was importing of the Component.

i had to change the below line

import MyCard from 'my-components-react';

to

import MyCard from 'my-components-react/es/MyCard';

Thanks

Comment: I am also trying to do the same but without success yet. I created an issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489358/host-react-component-in-angular-6-app . Please let me know if you have any thoughts