# How i can mixed React component to Angular

Tags: angular, reactjs, webpack, gulp

Hello colleagues I ask again, but I'll try to reformulate. I have a React component that needs to be embedded in the Angular application. The jsx file is imported, and through ReactDOM.render the file is rendered into one of the blocks. But the problem is that `angular-cli` can not do import jsx files.
Just i want use `angular-cli` for build angular application.

Can I build it so that I do not have to import jsx files and css files?

Comment: Refer this link, you  might need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840096/using-react-component-in-angular-2

Comment: This link have a complex solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408694/connect-angular-application-with-reactjs-app/54408718#54408718

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ngReact](https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact) libary for AngularJS: for Angular, I do not think there is a solution yet.

Comment: You can easy combine Angular & React - it's not a problem, and you doesn't need any special library.

Comment: @kris_IV can you elaborate on this at all?

Comment: @catch22 I create a complete answer on StackOverflow about this topic when I investigate for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54408718/2972087  
On the and of this answer you can look for demo and GitHub repository. Give me a feedback about it, maybe I can clarify something with more details.

Comment: @kris_IV Amazing work! Thanks for so clearly explaining this. You should make a module out of it when you get a chance ;)

Comment: @catch22 I thought about this, but I think that this implementation is simply when you understand it, and generally it should be flexible when you really want to use it. I didn't have any idea how can I create a module, that is flexible enough so I created this answer, demo and GitHub repo to share this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to bundle your component through a compiler (babel for example) and import it in your Angular application.

Then, as said [ForestG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3486691/forestg) you can use [ngReact](https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact) to wrap your React component into a directive and use it in your Angular App.