# Host React component in Angular 6 app

Tags: angular, reactjs

I am try to render React component in Angular 6.
The React component is from the tic-tac-toe tutorial
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-option-2-local-development-environment

Before referring to the React component, my Angular component which was going to be the host was working fine and printing the default text `component works`

The I modified the component and html file as follows:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <app-react-host-demo></app-react-host-demo>
  </div>
  <div id="demo-host"></div>
</div>




import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import {Square} from '../../../../../my-app/src/index.js';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-react-host-demo',
  templateUrl: './react-host-demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./react-host-demo.component.scss']
})
export class ReactHostDemoComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('demo-host')
  demoHost: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }  
}
```

I am getting error `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Can anyone please tell me how to get this working?

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: have you used an useEffect hook in the react component, and set it up to render only once?

Answer (score 0):

Install the React packages:

npm i --save react react-dom
npm i -D @types/react @types/react-dom

add to / update tsconfig.json:

"jsx": "react",
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
"strict" : false // optional

This example helped a lot:

https://github.com/zackypick/react-in-angular

An example Angular component hosting a React component:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges, OnDestroy, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { testPlatformProvider, Button } from '@test/test-ui-react';
import { ButtonSize, ButtonVariant } from '@test/test-ui-react/dist/types/components/Button/Button.types';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-test-button',
    template: ''
})
export class testButtonComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
    //https://react.ui.test/?path=/story/components-buttons-overview--page
    @Input() text = '';
    @Input() variant = 'primary';
    @Input() size = 'small';
    @Input() disabled: boolean;

    ElementToShow = () => (
        <testPlatformProvider>
            <Button variant={this.variant as ButtonVariant} size={this.size as ButtonSize} disabled={this.disabled}>
                {this.text}
            </Button>
        </testPlatformProvider>
    );

    constructor(private hostRef: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        //console.log('ngOnChanges: ' + this.hostRef.nativeElement);
        this.render();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        //console.log('ngAfterViewInit');
        this.render();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        //console.log('ngOnDestroy');
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.hostRef.nativeElement);
    }

    private render() {
        ReactDOM.render(<this.ElementToShow />, this.hostRef.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

Another example:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges, OnDestroy, Output, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { testPlatformProvider, Select } from '@test/test-ui-react';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-test-select',
    template: ''
})
export class testSelectComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
    //https://react.ui.test/?path=/story/components-select-overview--page
    @Input() inputId = '';
    @Input() label = '';
    @Input() value: any;
    @Input() options: any[];
    @Input() isRequired = 'false';
    @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

    ElementToShow = () => (
        <testPlatformProvider>
            <Select
                inputId={this.inputId}
                label={this.label}
                required={this.isRequired == 'true'}
                value={this.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}>
                {this.options && this.options.map((option: any) =>
                    <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
                )}
            </Select>
        </testPlatformProvider>
    );

    constructor(private hostRef: ElementRef) {
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        //console.log('select ngOnChanges: ' + this.hostRef.nativeElement);
        this.render();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        //console.log('ngAfterViewInit');
        this.render();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        //console.log('ngOnDestroy');
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.hostRef.nativeElement);
    }

    private render() {
        //console.log('select rendering');
        ReactDOM.render(<this.ElementToShow />, this.hostRef.nativeElement);
    }

    public handleChange(event: any): void {
        this.value = event.target.value;
        //console.log('select handleChange: ' + this.value);
        this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
        this.render();
    }
}
```